# PHP compare and merge

Tags: php, string, merge, compare

I'm new to PHP and have been reading up on how to compare and merge two string but failed.

This is pretty much what I'm trying to do

> **String 1**
>   xRed
>   Blue
>   Black
>   xYellow

**String 2**
xRed
xBlue
xBlack
xYellow
xGreen
xPink

> **Output**
>   xRed
>   Blue
>   Black
>   xYellow
>   xGreen
>   xPink

Comment: What's with the stars? Is that part of the strings?

Comment: You need to be more specific than saying "compare", there are many ways of comparing strings. I don't know what you are trying to do, please revise and I will be happy to help. Maybe providing us with the code that you failed with, so we can see what algorithm you're trying to create.

Comment: Sorry about that yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's like this?

```
<?php

$string1="red
blue
black
yellow";

$string2="red
blue
black
yellow
green
pink";

echo "<pre>";
echo implode("\r\n",array_unique(array_merge(explode("\r\n",$string1),explode("\r\n",$string2))));
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Sorry about that I'm trying to compare and merge.

Comment: So 'xBlue' replaces 'Blue'? What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score 0):

Java sets would be great for this...but, as far as PHP goes, I think exploding the string on a delimiter, reading through the chunks in a loop, and reassembling would be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$string1 = "red\nblue\nblack\nyellow";
$string2 = "red\nblue\nblack\nyellow\ngreen\npink";

$result = implode("\n", array_unique(explode("\n", "$string1\n$string2")));
```

(Note you can use the glue you want (\n,\r\n))